# How do set a custom minimum tab width in Safari 8?

Tags: safari, safari-extensions

In Chrome when I have many tabs open it simply reduces the width of each tab. I'm trying Safari for the first time in years and am not enjoying the tabs that get smaller towards the edge. Is there a clever tab setting or tab management extension? (Glims no longer works). I've spent >1 hr with my friend google but appear to be asking the wrong question.

Comment: I know about that am coming to tolerate it, but its not what I want. I would still prefer the chrome style without the chrome resource consumption.